# Need walk-through of how to create a user and assign a role to it in one form (ASP.NET Core MVC 3+)

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

1. Using ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1.
2. Added security using the identity scaffolding.
3. Created default groups following the instructions from **eShopOnWeb** (https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Identity/AppIdentityDbContextSeed.cs)
4. Able to seed the database and create
   3 groups: Admins, Managers, Users
   3 users: Admin, Manager, User
   assign the user to respective group.
5. I need instructions on how to accomplish assigning the roles to users from the User Management form (MVC pattern) at the time when I create a user or need to edit the roles for the users. Also I need MVC pattern not Razor pages like here https://github.com/bhrugen/Uplift/blob/master/Uplift/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs
   I presume I need to create the ViewModel which would include entries from **dbo.AspNetUsers**, **dbo.AspNetRoles**, **dbo.AspNetUserRoles** for that but not sure what exactly I need and how to perform.
6. Here is the desired functionality of the form
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo , you could refer to

*Models*

```
  public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}
  public class RegisterVM
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Birth date")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Management role")]
    public string role { get; set; }

    public List<IdentityRole> RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

*DbContext*

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

*Register view*

```
@model MVC3_1Identity.Models.ViewModels.RegisterVM

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BirthDate"></label>
            <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="City"></label>
            <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Country"></label> 
            <input asp-for="Country" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Country" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-checkbox">
            <label asp-for="role"></label>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.RoleList.Count; i++)
            {
               <input asp-for="role" type="radio" value="@Model.RoleList[i].Name" />
               <label asp-for="@Model.RoleList[i].Name">@Model.RoleList[i].Name</label>
            }
            <span asp-validation-for="role" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>

</div>

@section Scripts {
  <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

*Controller*

```
  public IActionResult Register()
    {
        var model = new RegisterVM();
        model.RoleList = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser 
            { 
                UserName = model.Email, 
                Email = model.Email,
                BirthDate=model.BirthDate,
                City=model.City,
                Country =model.Country,

            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,model.role).Wait();
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password and role.");
               // other logic you want

            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

*Startup.cs*

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser ,IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

Result:
[image]